# Angular Rxjs takeWhile operator occurs only once

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to keep sending request to the server with delay, but I When I put console log, I see that it does not occurs second time.

Here is my code:

```
this.siteStatusMessage.pipe(
      map(messageData => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messageData))),
      takeWhile(() => this.isAlive),
      delay(3000)
    ).subscribe();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show more code. What's the observable `this.siteStatusMessage` ? And where `isAlive` changed?

Answer (score 3):

For what I understand, you're trying to use `delay(3000)` to execute the observable every 3 seconds.

The `delay` operator, as its name states, just delays the emission of notifications. So in your example the observable will execute just once but emitting its notifications 3 seconds later than normal.

To execute the observable every 3 seconds, you need to use an `interval`.

```
interval(3000).pipe(
  switchMap((_) => this.siteStatusMessage.pipe(
      map(messageData => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messageData)))
  ),
  takeWhile(() => this.isAlive),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

takeWhile is taking a boolean, your functionlity seems like you want to use takeUntil(this.isAlive) in this case isAlive must be a subject/Observable a notifier.
Requirement is quite vague please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you want to delay the requests by 3 seconds each and keep doing them until you set your *isAlive* flag to false, you'd be better off with the *interval* pipe instead of *delay*.

I've compiled a script [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bkopk3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you to play around with. In the example, the string will be emitted every 3 seconds, until the flag turns false. You just need to replace the dummy observable with yours.